# Graphing 3 Variable Scatterplot R

Tags: r

I imported some data from Islander and am trying to graph something with 3 variables. I'm thinking of trying to graph 2 numeric variables with a nominal category (gender). The plot I'm trying to do therefore is a regular scatterplot, but color-coded.

I looked at this starter tutorial on R: Scatterplots, but didn't see any mention of 3 variable plotting.

http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/ssd-upgrade-tutorial

Can anyone help me out? My variables hold values pertaining to **number of balls bounced**, **minutes of physical activity per week**, and **gender**.

Picture of the data:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmAHK.png)

Comment: I've tried using plot(bounces, activity, gender), but it gave me a box-and-whisker instead. I've tried using a barplot, hoping that I could pass in the three arguments and color code gender. I'm fairly new to R @Stedy .

Comment: Can you just color by variable??  
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=disp, y= mpg,color = am)) +
  geom_point()

Comment: @user2600629 I tried to do that and even tried importing ggplot with library(ggplot), but it said it couldn't find the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since gender is a binary variable (usually, otherwise ternary), I would plot a 2D scatterplot with color encoding the gender.

Dummy data:

```
a = data.frame(x=runif(100), y = runif(100)+2, group = round(runif(100))+1 )
```

Now I would plot `y` against `x` using `a$group` to select the color:

```
plot(a$y, a$x, pch = 16, col = c('cornflowerblue', 'springgreen')[a$group])
```

Output:

[image: example]

If you do have missingness I would add a third group to the color vector. 
Here is a [bunch of other solutions for 2D scatter with color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466023/how-to-give-color-to-each-class-in-scatter-plot-in-r)

Comment: That helped so much! It looks great! Thank you for helping out. I didn't know you could do something like this.

Comment: No worries. The same principle applies to the choice of mark so you could use squares and triangles to separate the groups as well as color.

Comment: How would I have a legend that display that blue is male and green is female? I did ?plot but it didn't have any recommendations.

Comment: Something like `legend('bottomright', legend=c('male', 'female'), pch = c(16,16), col = c('cornflowerblue', 'springgreen') )` should work provided you have the male/female labels around the right way with the colors.